# What would be the C equivalent of rlwinm (PPC Instruction)

Tags: c, powerpc

I was wondering if any of you would know the C equivelent of the powerpc instruction below.

```
rlwinm    r31, r0, 0,13,13
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotate left register immediate, then `and` with mask.

Rotate left is 0 here, so we can ignore this. The mask is all bits set from 13 to 13, which is just bit 13 (0x2000 as a bitmask; this command was probably chosen over just `and` to document that bit 13 is selected).

So in this case, we need to build a mask for bit 13 and then apply bitwise `and` with the source.

```
r31 = r0 & (1 << 13);
```

`<<` is the shift left operation in C, we use it here to create a mask just for bit 13. `&` is the and operation in C.

Documentation source: http://sametwice.com/rlwinm

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I know I didn't ask this in the original question, but would you be able to briefly explain how this works?

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain how this works in more detail. If this is correct, you may want to accept the answer to close the question (add the checkmark on the left hand side)

Comment: Thanks again, I have accepted your answer as correct however I'm just wondering where the 1 came from?

 `1 << 13`

Comment: 1 is the bitmask for the lowest bit. We shift it by 13 to get a bitmask for bit 13. There is no built-in operation in C++ to just set bit 13, so this is as close as we get I think. Note that this is a constant expression, we could just write `r0 & 0x2000`